# Android locale support from Preferences

Tags: android, android-fragments, settings, locale, preference

I have a problem with my android app: I'm supporting multiple languages, but when I change the locale settings of the phone (Settings -> Language & input), my settings fragment shows only empty preferences on the screen. If I turn back to the original language, it remembers the preferences and shows them right. It seems to be a translation problem of the saved preferences but I don't really know how to fix it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/user" >
        <ListPreference 
            android:summary="@string/profile_summary" 
            android:title="@string/profile" 
            android:key="profiles" 
            android:entries="@array/profiles_array"
            android:entryValues="@array/profiles_array">
        </ListPreference>
        <ListPreference 
            android:summary="@string/sex_summary" 
            android:title="@string/sex" 
            android:key="sex" 
            android:entries="@array/sex_array"
            android:entryValues="@array/sex_array">
        </ListPreference>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="@string/general"
        android:defaultValue="true">
        <ListPreference 
            android:summary="@string/language_summary" 
            android:title="@string/language" 
            android:key="language" 
            android:entries="@array/languages_array"
            android:entryValues="@array/languages_array"
            android:defaultValue="@string/english">
        </ListPreference>
   </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you provide the translated strings? Some code will help diagnosing... especially the part where you set the new locale.

Comment: Yes I did. I don't update my locale by code, I simply switch default language of the phone. I tried by code too, but the result is the same. Thanks for the support

Comment: OK. Do you have a values-fr (for French), a values-es (for Spanish), a values-de (for German), ... and a values (for English) folders containing the translated strings?

Comment: Yes, I have three folders: 1.values-it 2.values-en 3.values. In "values" I put the same strings as "values-it". Is that a mistake?

Comment: Yes. values is only ENGLISH. So you shoud rename `values-en` to `values`. Leave only values and values-it. Then tell me.

Comment: Ok, I did it. But I have the same issue: when i change the phone locale, my app update all strings, but when i go in the preferences, all my radioboxes forgot their values. The preferences string are updated too, but the radioboxes appear empty. When i restore english locale, all comes true. I'm getting crazy for this, thanks for the support.

Comment: I added my /res/xml/settings.xml in my question, it seems to be well formed, except one thing: I used the same arrays for entryValues and enties because I use the strings show to the user as values of my preferences. Could be this an issue?

Comment: Entries are the list descriptions, while values are the compared strings (or integers to be used as indexes). It should be no issue - but I use a different string array here specifying the 2 char language code (in your case "en" and "it")

Comment: Ok I solved: due the use of translation strings as values, when I changed locale the app was looking for preferences in the past locale, that not matches with that in the new locale... what a dumb I am... :D  thanks for your patient support. I'm new here, should I update this post with a [SOLVED] label, or write the solution in a dedicated answer?

Comment: I think it's better to mark it as SOLVED